# How is [faa-approval] different from [pilot-certification]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Judging by the descriptions: how is [faa-approval](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-approval)<sup>[a]</sup> different from [pilot-certification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pilot-certification)?

Should the former be a synonym of the latter, and [faa](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa) to be used with the latter if needed?

It was [suggested in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57327524#57327524) that:

> it sounds like [faa-approval](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-approval) needs help then, because I suspect the former would make more sense for things the FAA has to supply approvals for specifically via LOA, OpSpec/MSpec, and so on

If that's the case, I think a better jurisdiction-neutral tag would be preferable, suggestions?

---

a: "The essential permission for a pilot to be authorized to operate an aircraft in US airspace."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite how it was originally described, it looks like the actual usage of faa-approval is mostly different from pilot-certification. So it seems that it would be best to rename the tag to be jurisdiction-neutral and cover approvals not included under more specific tags.