# Is [faa-approval] needed?

Tags: discussion, retagging

Carrying over from [How is [faa-approval] different from [pilot-certification]?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4178/14897)

The accepted answer after 2 weeks is:

> best to rename [[faa-approval](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-approval)] to be jurisdiction-neutral and cover approvals not included under more specific tags.

Having checked all the questions listed under that tag, and having googled "FAA Approval" to find an alternative, to me it seems like the tag is not needed -- i.e. vague (what SE calls a [meta tag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)).

Would retagging the ~27 questions to remove said tag be an issue, i.e. is there something I may have missed?